# Unknown IndexError while creating graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I am trying to ouput a graph of clusters after using PCA and k - means clustering using the following code:

```
Mergory=Mergory.astype(np.float32)
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(Mergory)
Mergory = scaler.transform(Mergory)
pca.fit(Mergory)
Mergory = pca.transform(Mergory)

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
kmeans.fit(Mergory)
labels = kmeans.predict(Mergory)
centroids = kmeans.cluster_centers_
```

and then i try to get the output in a graph using the following coding I found online:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))

colors = map(lambda x: colmap[x+1], labels)

plt.scatter(Mergory['hospitalizations_one_year'], Mergory['fried'], color=colors, alpha=0.5, edgecolor='k')
for idx, centroid in enumerate(centroids):
    plt.scatter(*centroid, color=colmap[idx+1])
plt.show()
```

and i get this error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-da3a8ac504f4> in <module>
      3 colors = map(lambda x: colmap[x+1], labels)
      4 
----> 5 plt.scatter(Mergory['hospitalizations_one_year'], Mergory['fried'], color=colors, alpha=0.5, edgecolor='k')
      6 for idx, centroid in enumerate(centroids):
      7     plt.scatter(*centroid, color=colmap[idx+1])

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

<Figure size 360x360 with 0 Axes>
```

Does anyone know to solve this or what is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

You transformed your `pd.DataFrame` into a `np.array` there:

```
Mergory = scaler.transform(Mergory)
pca.fit(Mergory)
Mergory = pca.transform(Mergory)
```

So, you can't use a column index on it, like you did here:

```
Mergory['hospitalizations_one_year'], Mergory['fried']
```

This example throws the same error:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.rand(4, 4)
arr['col 1']
```

> IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices